# UWP - Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, onesignal

I am trying to use oneSignal push notification sdk 8.1+ but get this exception.
see this : [Windows Phone SDK Installation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/windows-phone-81-sdk-install)

Does it mean I can't use it with uwp app ?

Exception :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,
Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of
its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match
the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Code :

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {   
    OneSignal.Init("OneSignal_App_Id", e, notificationOpened);
}

private void notificationOpened(string message, IDictionary<string, string> additionalData, bool isActive) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("notificationOpened:message:" + message);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("notificationOpened:additionalData:" + additionalData);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("notificationOpened:isActive:" + isActive);
}
```

Comment: OneSignal does not correctly work with UWP (Windows Universal Platform) apps.

Comment: @jkasten do you have any suggestion for uwp free push Service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To using OneSignal WP 8.1 SDK on UWP Project, Simply compile & test the project on release mode!!

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean I can't use it with uwp app ?

Seems so, we can't use it in UWP app.

> do you have any suggestion for uwp free push Service ?

Honestly, I don't know whether there is other free push service for UWP, which I can suggest is to use Mobile Apps in Azure App Service with Azure Notification Hubs. Here is the official document [Add push notifications to your Windows app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push/). The notification hubs is free, but you will need azure account for development, and this is not free. Although it may have some costs, but azure notification hubs is more stable and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's on their plans to implement it for UWP but there isn't any timeline on that. I think all we can do is just wait.